# Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException - Name [Class/object] is not bound in this Context

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, tomcat, ejb, cdi

have a problem that am dealing with since 6 hours but don't get to solve it.

Am developping a Dynamic web project using JSF/Tomcat 7/ Maven/Java 7

Everytime I run the project on the server I get this:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [....ProjectManagement/service] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [de.hhn.team3.artzpraxismanagement.ProjectManagement].
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.lookupFieldResource(DefaultInstanceManager.java:580)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.processAnnotations(DefaultInstanceManager.java:470)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.postConstruct(Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:90)
at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:213)
at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanResolver.java:333)
at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanResolver.java:296)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:169)
at org.apache.myfaces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:65)
at org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.VariableResolverToELResolver.getValue(VariableResolverToELResolver.java:123)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:169)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstEqual.getValue(AstEqual.java:38)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:96)
at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:263)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:1089)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:733)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:758)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:758)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1900)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:115)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

here is my Class ProjectManagement

```
 package ...artzpraxismanagement;

 @Named 
@ManagedBean 
@SessionScoped 
public class ProjectManagement implements Serializable {        
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;     
 @EJB   private Services service;
```

and my Service Class

```
@ManagedBean
```

> ```
> @SessionScoped
> @Local
> public class Services implements Serializable {...}
> ```

I have tried different solution like delete Tomcat Jars in WebContent/lib but it doesn't help.

I guess my `ProjectManagement` class is not bounded in the context.xml.

How can I do that please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EJBs and CDI don't work in Tomcat by default since Tomcat is just a Servlet Container. If you want to use them you must deploy your application on a real Java EE application server like [JBoss 7](https://www.jboss.org/jbossas/), [GlassFish 3](https://glassfish.java.net/) or [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) (note that these are free, there are others like IBM WebSphere and Oracle WebLogic that are Java EE 6 application servers but you must pay in order to acquire/use them). If you keep deploying this in Tomcat, you will never succeed.

If you still want to use Tomcat only, then get rid of all those `@EJB` and other Java EE annotations (e.g. CDI annotations like `@Named`).

By the way, please follow a good sane tutorial on JSF or CDI. You can't have a bean decorated as `@Named` and `@ManagedBean` at the same time.

Comment: +1. Luiggi, guess who is the most frequent user of the term '*sane tutorial*'? :)

Comment: @skuntsel we both know who =P

Comment: Thanks Luiggi!!! Have removed those annotations and now it's working!!! Anyway have to read a very good Tutorial